# appcelerator controllerless view addEventListener to elements within getView()

Tags: controller, view, appcelerator, event-listener, appcelerator-titanium

I am trying to require a simple view with 3 elements in into a page programatically.

This all works but i can only seem to bind an event to the main view, not individually. This below works for the main view but how would i apply an listener for an label element within partials.dropdown?  i tried views.name and it doesn't work unless i do getViews but then i don't know how to add them to the page :(

Code below: 
This is the controller:

```
var dropdown = Alloy.createController('partials/dropdown');
var views = dropdown.getView();

views.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    console.log(e.source);
});

$.product_guide.add(views);
```

this is the partial, i know it inst a drop down but its the same principal.

```
<Alloy>
    <View id='image_container'>
        <ImageView id='image;/>
        <Label id='label'/>
    </View>
</Alloy>
```

Many thanks

Comment: possible solution brought by previous question..  add event listener to views and then use e.source to determine which element was clicked

Answer (score 0):

`getView()` function optionally accepts a view's ID as an argument. Assign an ID to the child view and call the `getView()` function with the ID.

[Docs](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Alloy.Controller)

Comment: I tried that but if I did x = getview() and then do y = getview(Id) and apply a listener to that and then add x to the $.product_guide.add(x) the listener isn't picked up. Must be missing something. The listener is picked up if I add y but then only that is added

Comment: Maybe try binding event listeners after adding x?